# There was a problem with reindexing process - Rebuild Catalog product fulltext search index

Tags: magento-1.9

Problem with catalog search reindexing process.

Comment: what the issues you are facing?

Comment: http://prnt.sc/b0u5xl

Comment: did you get what i try to tell you

Comment: http://prnt.sc/b0u6gj

Comment: you can't able to reindex the catalog search right by manually?

Comment: then what i do for this problem

Comment: You can use shell to reindex. i will post the answer for it

Comment: its not working

Comment: This what i got the error http://prnt.sc/b0w50z

Comment: Any other remedies may as you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can reindex the all or individual data using following commands

```
**1 – Go to ‘shell’ folder in your Magento installation:**

cd shell

**2 – Execute reindex using this command:**

php -f indexer.php reindexall

It is possible to get full list of Magento indexer commands using this command:

php -f indexer.php help

To get a list of available indexes, execute this command:

php -f indexer.php info

**By default there are 8 indexes in Magento:**

catalog_product_attribute     Product Attributes
catalog_product_price         Product Prices
catalog_url                   Catalog Url Rewrites
catalog_product_flat          Product Flat Data
catalog_category_flat         Category Flat Data
catalog_category_product      Category Products
catalogsearch_fulltext        Catalog Search Index
cataloginventory_stock        Stock status

**Individual commands for re-indexing:**

php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
php indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
php indexer.php --reindex tag_summary
```

Comment: Any other remedies may as you know.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can run indexing by CLI

   `php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext`

[image]

CMD to RUN Command

[image]
2. Make sure that the `var/` folder has the correct file permissions and ownership because Magento writes to this directory

3. Increase Memory limit

   `ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');`

Comment: how can i go to cd shell

Comment: cmd -> cd C:\wamp\www\giri\shell

Comment: Am using above command in cmd

Comment: check updated answer with `Shell` directory shown

Comment: I couldn't get you.

Comment: check CMD screenshot added

Comment: i got this result     http://prnt.sc/b0ufxf

Comment: take a backup of `catalogsearch_fulltext`, `catalogsearch_query` and `catalogsearch_result` tables and TRUNCATE them. Then try re-indexing by command

Comment: are you sure i have 15 thousands of products

Comment: That's why I'm telling you to take a `BACKUP FIRST` and do `TRUNCATE`  :)

Comment: http://prnt.sc/b0xyty

Comment: can you please translate this error msg to english?

Comment: Any other remedies may as you know.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open Terminal go to magento root folder via this command  `cd Magento Root Folder`

2) and fire this command `php -f shell/indexer.php reindex`

Comment: All are re-indexed except  :   php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext                                                                        http://prnt.sc/b0uwcg

Comment: restart  your system and try again

Comment: Its not working, after restart

Comment: This what i got the error http://prnt.sc/b0w50z

Comment: Any other remedies may as you know.

Comment: Do you use any extension for product view or listing page?? Might be that extension may overwrite core file and has no added this one module for reindex

Comment: No, am not installed extensions for product view or listing page.

Comment: Can i upgrade my magento version, currently am using 1.9.2.3, right after may solve this error ??

Comment: I dont think its related to magento version

Comment: please provide your system->indexmanagment screen shot

Comment: http://prnt.sc/b1x1dx

Comment: It may issue with your MySql timeout check that way and increase your mysql timeout and try again

Comment: How can i do this

Comment: How can i increase MySql timeout

Comment: Where i can go to  increase MySql timeout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39491/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-murtuza).